# is possible to get/download file from API links that don't have real file path in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, download

i try to get some downloadable file from api without return real file path,example like [www.domain.com/api/get-audio?name=foo.mp3](http://www.domain.com/api/get-audio?name=foo.mp3), when open in browser file will automatically be downloaded but it seems that in Unity there must be some function to be able to download the file somehing like :

```
IEnumerator GetTheFoo(string path)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(path))
    {
        www.SendWebRequest();
        while (www.downloadProgress < 0.01)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.downloadProgress);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
        }
        if (www.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log("error");
        }
        else
        {  
            Debug.Log(Application.persistentDataPath);
            string savePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}.mp3", Application.persistentDataPath, "foo");        
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(savePath, www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

i got the file but after i chek the file is return the wrong size and maybe not sound file beacuse i cant play it,i deep searching on google for the best way to download file and i see all example and solusition given is with link with real path file like file/audio/foo.mp4, so is possible or not to get downloadable file from API or link that not contain real path?

**[UPDATE]**

100% is my own fault, sorry for lack of knowledge
i dont know if the while will change the result so just change yield return with some correct logic or just replace them with only

`yield return www.SendWebRequest();`

Comment: `while (www.downloadProgress < 0.01)` so, you wait until download has reach 1% ?

Comment: i got example from this answer https://answers.unity.com/questions/1574355/can-we-stream-audio-from-a-url-instead-of-download.html

Comment: Did you read the comment of the answer provided in the link ?

Comment: yeah he say "I got this to work using the following code",you think the code not correct?

Comment: ok i will try it

Comment: great,you are right this my bad.change the `yield return` fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do

```
while (www.downloadProgress < 0.01)
{
    Debug.Log(www.downloadProgress);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
}
```

So you wait until you have `1%` downloaded and then try to save the file. You should rather wait until everything is downloaded e.g.

```
while (www.downloadProgress < 1f)
{
    Debug.Log(www.downloadProgress);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
}
```

or if you don't need the progress update anyway you could also directly use

```
yield return www.SendWebRequest();
```

---

Then afaik MP3 files are not UTF8 encoded so you should rather use the **binary** [`DownloadHandler.data`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandler-data.html)!

Also for system file paths rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) instead of string concat (+ "/")

```
var savePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "foo" + ".mp3");  
File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, www.downloadHandler.data);
```

---

So in total like

```
IEnumerator GetTheFoo(string path)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(path))
    {
        www.SendWebRequest();
        while (www.downloadProgress < 1)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.downloadProgress);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
        }

        if (www.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log("error");
        }
        else
        {  
            var savePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "foo.mp3");        
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, www.downloadHandler.data);

            Debug.Log($"File saved to {savePath}", this);
        }
    }
}
```

which works perfectly fine for me e.g. passing in

```
https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3
```

as parameter ;)

Comment: great,you are right,is my bad.change the `return yield` fix that and thank for the correct syntax.I'm really sorry for my mistake